# What is the best way to display an icon for removing the row in a table?

Tags: tables, data-tables, delete, space-constraints

I am designing a system where users need to be able to delete a table row.

Originally I had a 'remove' button, but that has now changed to an icon in the interest of saving space.  I have used a red 'x' for[image]:

Is this clear enough, I am also wondering how it should be styled.  I don't like it being displayed in it's own cell, but I am afraid that removing the border will make it seem immediately relevant to the sub-specialty.

Thoughts please?

Comment: Why don't you use a checkbox + separate remove/delete button to support group action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not saying this is the "best", but the current version of MS Outlook shows the delete icon only when the mouse is hovered over the row:
[image: Grayed delete icon]

And then turns it to red when the mouse hovers over the delete button:
[image: Red delete icon]

Note that the icon they use is subtly different- the slightly "curved" X implies "delete/remove" as opposed to a straight X which in my mind is more of a "stop" icon.

Comment: in hotmail it is similar but they use a dustbin/trash can icon which I think is more specific to delete.